# BASH remove specific tokens from a word

Tags: bash

I am trying to find te longest word in a given file. Before I check the lengtgh of each word I need to remove all of the following tokens {,.:} that may be attached (once or more) to the word. so for example, for this text:

> :,cat dog, encyclopedia; remove:.,

i need the result:

> cat dog encyclopedia remove

I am trying this, but I get a "command not found":

```
longest=0
for word in $(<$1)
do
    #new_word = $(echo "${word//[.,:]/}")
    new_word = "${word//[.,:]/}"
    len=${#new_word}

    if (( len > longest ))
    then
        longest=$len
        longword=$new_word
    fi
done
echo The longest word is $longword and its length is $longest.
```

thank you.

Comment: `echo ":,cat dog, encyclopedia; remove:.," | tr -d ':;.,'`?

Comment: **No space around the `=` sign.**

Comment: And by the way, [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: If your file contains `*`, for example, it'll be replaced with a list of filenames in the current directory -- surely not what you want. Consider instead: `read -r -a words <"$1"; for word in "${words[@]}"; do`

Comment: The problem with `new_word = ...anything...` is that you can't have spaces around the `=` in an assignment; once you have a space, it's running `new_word` as a command with `=` as its first argument.

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ would have identified that for you automatically.

Comment: it was the spaces, rookie mistake... thank you to everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of parameter expansion replacement pattern is correct.

The problem is that there must not be any whitespace around `=` while declaring variables in `bash` (any shell in general).

So, the following should work:

```
new_word="${word//[.,:]/}"
```

---

As an aside, use a `while read ...` construct to loop over the lines in a file, using `for` is pretty fragile.